# Pretty-printing C# from Python

Tags: c#, python, ruby, parsing, pretty-print

Suppose I wrote a compiler in Python or Ruby that translates a language into a C# AST.

How do I pretty-print this AST from Python or Ruby to get nicely indented C# code?

```
Thanks, Joel
```

Answer (score 1):

In python the [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) module is available.

Depending on how your data is structured it may not return the result your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have an AST, this should be very easy.  When you walk your AST, all you have to do is keep track of what your current indent level is -- you could use a global for this.  The code that's walking the tree simply needs to increment the indent level every time you enter a block, and decrement it when you exit a block.  Then, whenever you print a line of code, you call it like this:

```
print "\t"*indentlevel + code
```

You should end up with nicely formatted code.  However, I'm a bit confused that you're asking this question -- if you have the skills to parse C# into an AST, I can't imagine you wouldn't be able to write a pretty-printing output function. :-)

Answer (score -2):

One way would be to just print it and then invoke a code formatter.